# How to use Open CV in android?

Tags: android, opencv

how to use open CV in java android. can we edit the template from open CV too? like change gaussian blur with our own formulas?

Comment: You can learn about open cv from some books which you can get from http://www.filtrlink.com and search for opencv in the search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this links which will help you to understand the the openCV concept in ANDROID:
http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

You can match the templates through OpenCV in ANDROID. So, i think you can also edit it as well. Check above link. These will surely help you.

Comment: You can learn about open cv from some books which you can get from http://www.filtrlink.com and search for opencv in the search box